# Passing data won't update the string

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a table view with a tap gesture recognizer inside of it and when I double click on the cell, I wanted to pass data from the cell to another view controller. Now it works only once and doesnt update the string in the view controller. The string remains permanent. Now I need help updating the string so that when I try to double tap another cell, the string will update instead of only work once by keeping the value of the string in the view controller constant with that of the first cell tapped. Here is my code.

Code in tableview for double tap gesture recognizer.

```
 func CellTappedTwice(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer!) {

    if let index = sender.view?.tag{
        if let object = objects?[index]{
            if let objectId = object.objectId{
                popupViewController.objectId = objectId
            }
        }
    }
    self.present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Code in view controller:

```
var objectId : String?
@IBOutlet weak var QrCode: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let object = objectId {
        let qrcode = DCQRCode(info: object, size: CGSize(width: 170, height: 170))
        qrcode.positionStyle = [
            (UIImage(named: "RedOuterPosition")!, DCQRCodePosition.topRight),
            (UIImage(named: "RedOuterPosition")!, DCQRCodePosition.topLeft),
            (UIImage(named: "RedOuterPosition")!, DCQRCodePosition.bottomLeft)
        ]
        qrcode.maskImage = UIImage(named: "RedColors")
        QrCode.image = qrcode.image()
        print("hello\(objectId)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code in your popup view controller that takes the objectID string and displays it. Also show how your `popupViewController` gets created and where you store it.

Comment: BTW, you can rework your 2 `if let` statements into 1: `if let index = sender.view?.tag, let object = objects?[index], let objectId = object.objectId` and get rid of your nested indenting. Each step in a compound `if let` stops evaluating the statement if it fails, and if it succeeds, that new variable becomes available to the next step.

Comment: I edited it, please look at it and give me your feedback

Comment: @Duncan C, Can you please tell me what you think

Comment: Dude, calm down. Don't post a request for replies and then a follow-up 15 minutes later. That is over-the-top impatient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that handles objectId to your `viewWillAppear(_:)` method, not viewDidLoad. The viewDidLoad method only gets called once during the life of a view controller, so if you're using the same view controller over and over, you'll only every process `objectId` the first time it's displayed.

Comment: would it not be better to move this into a delegate call?  `viewWillAppear` could be called for other reasons as well, and you may not have data from the first controller

Comment: ViewWillAppear will be called when the view controller is about to be displayed, which is exactly what you want. Yes, you could set up a protocol and delegate, but what I describe will work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for all your help